# Backbone View Event not firing when changing el property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and trying to do some examples, but I'm stuck with this one.
I have the below BackBone View:

```
CommentBoxView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template( $("#comment_box_template").html(), {} );
        this.el.html(template);
    },
    events: {
        "keypress textarea": "doKeyPress"
    },
    doKeyPress: function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
});
```

Everything's running ok but if I replace

> this.el.html(template);

with this:

> this.el = $(template).replaceAll(this.el);

The keypress event is not fired at all.
Could anyone please explain to me why it happened and how to make this code works? Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Backbone uses the view's [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) method to bind a jQuery [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) call to the view's [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el), this `delegate` is what handles all the view's events. If you do this:

```
this.el = $(template).replaceAll(this.el);
```

you lose the `delegate` bound to `this.el` and your events go with it. You'll also end up with your [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el) not matching `this.el` and that's not good either. The proper way to change a view's `el` is to use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement):

> **setElement** `view.setElement(element)`
>
> If you'd like to apply a Backbone view to a different DOM element, use **setElement**, which will also create the cached `$el` reference and move the view's delegated events from the old element to the new one.

So you should be able to do it like this:

```
this.setElement($(template).replaceAll(this.el));
```